# POWER BI - Sorting product id in order of sales by region in a "line and clustered column chart" + applying top 5 to each region

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a "Line and Clustered Column" where I want to show the top 5 sales (of product ID) by region. Both Product ID and Region will be in x-axis, and Sales will be the y-axis. There is also a secondary y-axis which captures the return rate of each product id for each region (in line). I encountered problem in two parts.

1. I cannot sort the product id in descending order of sales for each region. It seems that when i sort, the products will be sorted by descending order, disregarding the region.
2. I am unable to limit each region by top 5 sales. When I did it through the default filtering option, it returns me the top 5 products in sales, disregarding the region.

These has baffled me for 1 day (I am new in power BI but not in visualization so I thought this is straight forward). I have not applied any DAX to the chart and I fear that the solution might require it.

So if you can help me in this, and help me on what to do , it would be EXTREMELY useful.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: taking photos of your screen using a camera: this isn't 1970. Please learn to use the screenshot functionality of your operating system. (it's **literally** a single keypress... this is a bit silly.) Alos, this seems to have nothing to do with programming!

Comment: Will provide screenshot tomorrow as i was having internet issue with my power bi laptop. Thanks for your feedback. Also, if it's related go DAX, then it's got to do with programming (unfortunately)